# NuGet Package List Empty on TeamCity NuGet Server

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, nuget-server

I've set up TeamCity (9.1.6) to work as a NuGet server. I have a project that I added a NuGet Pack build step. The artifacts of that build configuration are *.nupkg files.

However, when I view either the authenticated or the guest NuGet feed, the package list is empty.

I've reset the buildMetadata cache and even restarted the build server.

What am I missing?

Edit: here's what the artifacts looks like for my project:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem.  NO matter what I do, the feed is empty.  All *.nuget files are published, the server is configured, I check both the auth and non-auth feed and they are empty.  Nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the .nupkg isn't showing as an artifact then it won't be in the feed. Without knowing the output directory settings, I can't tell you the correct value for the build artifact path. However, the simplest option is to ensure the checkbox is ticked that forces packages to be published as build artifacts.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: The .nukpg files *are* in my build artifacts (my question briefly noted this). I've updated my question with a screenshot of the artifacts for the project. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: How are you accessing the NuGet feed?

Comment: Viewing raw feed in a browser. Packages collection is empty.

Comment: Ah. It does this :( Add the feed as a package source to something like Visual Studio and you'll see your packages.

Comment: Wow. That is just weird. I swear I had tried it in Visual Studio earlier and it showed nothing. But I just redid everything and there it is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah. I discovered that it wasn't showing up in studio because the NuGet packages were targeting a higher version of the framework than the project I was adding them to. Once I updated the project to match the framework version, they showed up as expected.

Comment: All packages have that "publish" box checked.  Target versions of .NET match.  I'm viewing it in Visual Studio.  Nothing.  EDIT -> Turns out that not all the binaries were configured to use the same target version.  If only one in the solution is incorrect, the packages won't show up.  That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue, and it eventually worked.

My issue was I was running Personal Builds not Full Builds.  Even though it would still make the package as an artifact, it wouldn't publish to the newsfeed.

```
[Step 15/15] Packages from personal builds are not published to ******* NuGet Feed
```

It even said as much in the Build Log (as shown above)

Comment: so, what's your solution than?

Comment: Run a Full Build :).  Our solve is to have a new NuGet project in Team City that runs a Full Build